# How to set default please select option with select control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ng-options to create select options. 
CA.JSON file has all the controls values/options.

Here in for VehicleYear option I want to add default please select option.

```
<select>
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="2017">2017<option>
...
<select>
```

I tryed as below but its not working

```
<select ng-change="updateMakeList" custom-required="true" ng-options="ans._value as ans._promptText for ans in questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._answerOptions" ng-model="answers.VehicleYear" ng-required="queObj._required" class="form-control {{queObj._pageAttributes.cssclass}}" name="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" id="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" data-que-obj="questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData" select-control-dir setMake custom-required>
                              <option value="">Please select</option>
                            </select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview

Comment: `<option value="" selected>Please select</option>`

Comment: Please select option is not showing in list. How to add out of ng-options.

Comment: how to change the `answers.VehicleYear`? Your code is extremely hard to debug. In app.js if I add `$rootScope.answers = {PC: 12345, VehicleYear: null};` it's initialized to 2017...

Comment: Otherwise here I added an empty option inside the json file like you did for the other selects https://plnkr.co/edit/KMXVePXWIj8OwSapmPvU?p=preview

Comment: In Json I don't want to add empty option.

Comment: @gyc VehicleYear you can set value those are available in select options.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code for select

```
<select ng-init="selectModal= Please Select" 
        ng-model="selectModal" 
        ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>
```

// where options is your options array in your case i think its questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._answerOptions

you can also try by adding option as below

```
<option style="display:none" value="">Please select</option>
```

When you try to assign value to option which is not in options array or set this problem occurs

[Updated code without style](https://plnkr.co/edit/MVlOwOrplGfimNMmArjz?p=preview)

Comment: questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._answerOptions have list of years only. On UI i want to add please select as first option if ng model do not have value for that node it should be selected..

Comment: Are you try my code after updation "selectModal= Please Select"  or  adding   <option value="" selected>--Please select your color--</option>?

Comment: Finally its work after adding    <option style="display:none" value="">Please select</option>

Comment: Please refer my link in answer for all required changes. you can add your stlyes as I removed just for testing

Comment: select-control-dir directive is required to add with each select control. If I add this "select a type option" gets removed.